# Issue with my template

Tags: fancyhdr, templates, sublime-text

For all my documents, I created a template.tex file which is imported in all my files. But it says that I got those issues :

```
/home/rperrod/rp/PERSO/LaTeX/Test/template/t.tex:20: Undefined control sequence. [  \setlength{\footheight}{10mm}]
/home/rperrod/rp/PERSO/LaTeX/Test/template/t.tex:20: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [  \setlength{\footheight}{10mm}]
/home/rperrod/rp/PERSO/LaTeX/Test/template/t.tex:25: Undefined control sequence. [  \allowdisplaybreaks]
```

Heres my test file :

```tex
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    
      \usepackage[english, french]{babel}
      \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \usepackage{varwidth}
      
    %----------- My template file ---------
      
      \geometry{
        a4paper,
        left=16mm,
        top=16mm,
        bottom=16mm,
        right=16mm
      }
    
      \pagestyle{fancy}
      \fancyhf{}
      \setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
      \lhead{\textsc{Some Text}}
      \rhead{\textsc{SOME} Text}
      \setlength{\footheight}{10mm}
      \rfoot{\thepage}
      \date{}
      \author{}
    
      \allowdisplaybreaks
    
    %-----------------------------------
    
      \title{I'm a giraffe}
    
    \begin{document}
    
      \maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
    
      Lorem ipsum
    
      \section{Colorado}
    
      \newpage
    
      \newpage
    
      \section{Says}
    
      \newpage
    
      \section{Giraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffe}
    
    \end{document}
```

Where's the issue ? I just copied this from my friend and for him, it works. Did I forget a certain package ?

Comment: Off-topic: `left=16mm, top=16mm, bottom=16mm, right=16mm` may expressed more succinctly as `margin=16mm`.

Comment: `\footheight` should probably be `\footskip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to include `headheight` and `footskip` (not `footheight`) in the geometry definition, rather than separately with `\setlength`.

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

```
  \usepackage[english, french]{babel}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage{varwidth}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  
%----------- My template file ---------
  
  \geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=16mm,
    top=16mm,
    bottom=16mm,
    right=16mm,
    headheight=10mm,
    footskip=10mm,
  }

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \lhead{\textsc{Some Text}}
  \rhead{\textsc{SOME} Text}
  \rfoot{\thepage}
  \date{}
  \author{}

  \allowdisplaybreaks

%-----------------------------------

  \title{I'm a giraffe}

\begin{document}

  \maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}

  Lorem ipsum

  \section{Colorado}

  \newpage

  \newpage

  \section{Says}

  \newpage

  \section{Giraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The format of the error mssages you show is misleading as it obscures which command is undefined.

The first error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \footheight 
                       
l.23       \setlength{\footheight}{10mm}
                                        
?
```

If you comment out line 23, and re-run, then you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.28       \allowdisplaybreaks
```

Which is a command from `amsmath` which has not been loaded, so add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

You also get

```
Package french.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.
(french.ldf)                Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble
(french.ldf)                of your document; reported on input line 35.
```

so putting that all together, no warnings or errors from:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage[english, french]{babel}
      \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \usepackage{varwidth}
      \usepackage{amsmath}

    %----------- My template file ---------
      
      \geometry{
        a4paper,
        left=16mm,
        top=16mm,
        bottom=16mm,
        right=16mm
      }
    
      \pagestyle{fancy}
      \fancyhf{}
      \setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
      \lhead{\textsc{Some Text}}
      \rhead{\textsc{SOME} Text}
%      \setlength{\footheight}{10mm}
      \rfoot{\thepage}
      \date{}
      \author{}
    
      \allowdisplaybreaks
    
    %-----------------------------------
    
      \title{I'm a giraffe}
    
    \begin{document}
    
      \maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
    
      Lorem ipsum
    
      \section{Colorado}
    
      \newpage
    
      \newpage
    
      \section{Says}
    
      \newpage
    
      \section{Giraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffe}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It works but the page number is kinda messy

Comment: @Romaing69 see Pieter's answer, he does know something about `fancyhdr`